# Java and mySQL select from related database index

Tags: mysql

I need some help understanding this.since I've never done something similar to this.

I have made a small database where 3 tables are related together. 
In that database I am selecting from a foreign key called cid and its related to a table where it has as primary key cid.

I made this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales,continent,product 
WHERE sales.cid = continent.cid OR sales.pid = product.pid
```

so I am trying to pull everything from the related databases. I can see it working on my code normally I think for example if  execute the query and then
I do a ResultSet to pull the string for example product.SKU i will get the expected result.

but did I really use my relation or I just pulled it cause my query is allowing me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join 3 tables, but this is not the way to do it.
Check this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales
INNER JOIN continent ON sales.cid = continent.cid
INNER JOIN product ON sales.pid = product.pid
```

This way you join `continent` to `sales` and `product` to `sales` by their related columns.
Depending on your needs you may use `INNER` or `LEFT` joins, but this is the way to go.
 You can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: thanks for correcting this. ill have a read of the documentation you send me to further understand whats going on